# How do I get the size of all stack-allocated variables for a stack frame in the Visual C++ Debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm stepping through someone else's C++ code trying to find memory hogs using the Visual Studio (2013) debugger.

My question is: how do I create a list of all stack-allocated objects and their size?

I know I get the size of a single object by typing `typeof(myObject)` into the "Immediate Window". However, I don't want to manually do that for every single object.

Coming from clang/lldb, I'm used to a rich, programmable debugger API. Does visual studio have something like that (probably based on powershell)?

Comment: Is something wrong with this question? Why the downvote?

Comment: Is the VS Diagnostic tool helpful for you like the memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the Memory usage tool under Debugger diagnostic tools:

Attach to devenv.exe after it’s started to use memory, take a memory snapshot, wait a bit, take another snapshot.

[image]

Reference:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/04/02/diagnosing-memory-issues-with-the-new-memory-usage-tool-in-visual-studio/